# Sharepoint designer 2013 - Loop versus wait for item update

Tags: sharepoint-designer, loop

When would you use a "loop" in a list workflow versus "wait for item update"?

Advantages/disadvantages of each.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's like everything in computer science: *polling* versus *events*.
When you poll (querying the status of an object in a loop), there's 2 drawbacks:

1. It may consume unnecessary resources since code runs for nothing most of the time.
2. There may be a delay between the time the event actually occurred and the time you poll and know it occurred.

While with an event ("wait for item update"), you have no worries like that: your workflow really sleeps till the event occurs, and you're notified immediately (note: in the SharePoint workflow world, "immediately" means "with a 5-minute max delay").

Comment: But how do you stop a workflow with a "wait for item update" if the person ignores the email and the workflows? With a loop, I can end the workflow.  Let's say for example, the workflow is waiting for an item update and the update never occurs and it's past the due date.  How do I end that workflow?  I've seen several workflows like that at my current place of employment where the event never occurred so they were just running for 12 plus months.

Comment: @PattiN One possibility is to pause inside a loop. Having a long pause will prevent it from consuming too many resources.